# celery custom library in task file causing ImportError: cannot import name 'foo'

Tags: python, django, git, celery

I am trying to use a custom library in a celery task file,but whenever I am try to start the worker there is a `ImportError: cannot import name 'foo'` error.

These are the versions of django and celery I am using, along with an example of the custom python library that is being installed from a git repo.

```
celery==4.0.2
-e git+https://gitlab.com/my-repo#egg=foo
Django==1.10.5
```

If I don't try in import the custom library, the celery and the worker process runs without any issues.

This is what the project structure looks like.

```
.
├── app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── connect_test.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tasks.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
└── web_project
    ├── celery.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

thanks

Comment: where you have imported foo? did makemigrations worked?

Comment: foo is being imported from a virtual environment and makemigrations  do work.